# How do I lookup a value in a table?

Tags: go, assembly, arm, arm64

In Go assembly on arm64, I have created a table of values

```
DATA table<>+0(SB)/4, 0x00000001
DATA table<>+4(SB)/4, 0x00000002
DATA table<>+8(SB)/4, 0x00000003
DATA table<>+12(SB)/4, 0x00000004
```

But what I want to be able to do is load up a value into a register from this table, but based on a variable.

If I had a constant I could do

```
MOVD table<>+4(SB), R1
```

so R1=0x00000002

but how can I do it with a variable? Something like...

```
MOVD $4, R0
MOVD table<>+R0(SB), R1
```

Or better yet, can I get the address and load a vector directly?

I guess the answer in normal are is ADR, but when I try that in go

```
ADR table<>(SB), R0
```

I just get

```
asm: illegal combination: 00280 [...] ADR table<>(SB), R9 ADDR NONE NONE REG, 3 7
```

Which is maybe the least useful error message I've ever seen.

Okay, so ADR works if I do PC relative addressing, but that's obviously not right.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it's really easy, you just put a $ before the variable

```
MOVD $table<>+0(SB), R0
```